# Can hasattr go multiple children deep in Python?

Tags: python

If I have `node.child1.child2`, can I use h`asattr(node, 'child1.child2')` effectively? Will it error if there's no `child1` or simply return false?

Comment: Try see. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, please actually run the code and post the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hasattr` doesn't take a dotted name like that and navigate down attribute chains.  But you can write a function to do it:

```
def get_deep_attr(obj, attrs):
    for attr in attrs.split("."):
        obj = getattr(obj, attr)
    return obj

def has_deep_attr(obj, attrs):
    try:
        get_deep_attr(obj, attrs)
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
def hasattrdeep(obj, *names):
    for name in names:
       if not hasattr(obj, name):
            return False
       obj = getattr(obj, name)
    return True
```

Call it like this:

```
hasattrdeep(node) is True  # A side-effect. Could be made invalid if really desired by raising TypeError if len(names) == 0
hasattrdeep(node, 'foo') is False
hasattrdeep(node, 'child1') is True
hasattrdeep(node, 'child1', 'foo') is False
hasattrdeep(node, 'child1', 'child2') is True
```